# Select All Posts With All Their Tags

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

There are many questions about this, but not enough definitive answers, especially using SQL Server which I am in this case.

I have 3 tables to represent blog posts and tags associated with it. I want to run a query that will get all the posts and each posts tags with it - I need both the tag id and name. The result needs to be easily serializable into my C# classes. I am also trying to use Dapper.net but that is not the most important part.

Obviously many websites do this, I want to know the best way and how it should be done in the real world? I could get all the posts, then run multiple queries for each one afterwards that would return the tags for each post. But surely there has to be a better way?

If I was just attempting to get one post then I would just write multiple selects. One for the post and one for the tags. But I want all of the posts. Is there a way of doing this without replicating the post information for each tag row that is returned?

If the tags for each post are serialized into a column that has them comma separated for example, how would one be able to get both the id and the name? Encode the string?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Posts    
SELECT * FROM dbo.Tags
SELECT * FROM dbo.PostTags

Posts
Id  Title       Content
===============================
1   First Post  First Content
3   Second      Second Content

Tags
Id  Name
============
1   C#
2   SQL
3   IIS
4   Steam
5   OpenID

PostTags
PostId  TagId
=============
1       1
1       2
3       3
3       4
```

Simply joining the tables with the following query:

```
SELECT p.*, t.Name
FROM dbo.Posts p
LEFT JOIN dbo.PostTags pt ON p.id = pt.PostId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Tags t ON t.id = pt.TagId
```

Gives much redundant data by repeating the post content for each tag that is associated with it:

```
Id  Title       Content         Name
======================================
1   First Post  First Post      C#
1   First Post  First Post      SQL
3   Second Post Second Content  IIS
3   Second Post Second Content  Steam
```

Comment: It would be a pretty ugly hack, but I've seen it used in production before... Would you be OK with combining them into a single column and then parsing them on the C# end? For example, the tags column could look like: "{{{1|||C#}}}{{{2|||SQL}}}", and so on (in the format of {{{ID|||Name}}}...)

Comment: Well I was thinking that, I was hoping to see what the best practice was regarding this sort of thing - I assume it's quite a common thing no?

I was also hoping to use Dapper.net (a micro ORM) - I don't think it could deal with that sort of thing out of the box.

Comment: This is definitely very far from best practices (especially when you are talking about .NET and OOP, along with an ORM), but it is sometimes used in the real world (as are many other very hacky things) due to performance and bandwidth considerations. Another, possibly better way which is still somewhat old-fashioned but not as ugly as the one above is to return multiple result sets (don't know if Dapper could handle that). So then in the first result se the tags column would just have a comma-delimited list of tag ID's, and the second result set an actual list of tags (and what they mean).

Comment: A comma-separated list of tag ID's (and only ID's), as in my second example, is actually not that bad of a practice. The first example I gave is, but may work as a very quick solution if you run into limitations with other approaches.

Comment: And just match tag id with tag name by the order they appear in the different sets or columns?  Sounds possibly better than encoding the strings somehow.  But would probably still require custom serializing code which isn't too much of a problem I guess but is annoying to stop using Dapper now when I've already started. I wonder how stack overflow gets data for the main page where they are displaying lots of questions and the tags for each one. They also use Dapper apparently?  This seems like such a simple problem but maybe not?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Not necessarily in the order they appear. The second result set would just be another table with ID->TagName, and the IDs would be organic. The first set would also have organic tag ID's; then you can just join them using LINQ on the C# side. Ideally, however, instead of using two result sets, you would have all of the tags cached on your web server and then you can just reference what you have in the cache.

Comment: StackOverflow uses a bunch of different platforms, including Redis as a distributed cache. I'm sure the data that is fed into their web presentation layer bears little resemblance to how they store it in the database...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

This being purely an exercise, let me preface this by saying that most likely the amount of data being duplicated isn't a big deal. Although if the posts are very large in size and there are lots of them, it does start to make more sense to avoid duplication.

Further, using C# Linq-to-Sql or Entity Framework, the object relationships will be worked out for you and your `Post` entity will have a `List<Tag>` property that you can access.

However if you want to roll your own type of thing, one option that involves just one DB round trip and no duplication of data is to write a stored proc that gets you back 2 recordsets (2 separate select statements) - one with Post content, and one with Tag content.

It would then be pretty simple to create a C# class that represents a `Post` and just has a `List<Tag>` and pull it from the stored proc results.

```
Create Procedure GetPostTags
As

-- We will use the GotTags column here to loop through and get tabs later
Declare @Posts Table (
    PostID varchar(50), 
    PostTitle varchar(50), 
    PostContent varchar(50),
    GotTags bit default 0
)

/* Assuming you care about the ID's, this will get you all of 
   the tags without duplicating any post content */
Declare @PostTags Table (
    PostID int,
    TagID int,
    TagName varchar(50)
)

-- Populate posts from the main table
Insert Into @Posts (PostID, PostTitle, PostContent)
Select * From Posts

-- Now loop through and get the tags for each post. 
Declare @CurrentPostID int
Set @CurrentPostID = (Select Top 1 PostID From @Posts Where GotTags = 0)
While @CurrentPostID Is Not Null
    Begin
        Insert Into @PostTags (PostId, TagID, TagName)
        Select pt.postid, pt.tagid, t.name
        From Tags t 
            Join PostTags pt
                On t.id = pt.tagid
        Where pt.postid = @CurrentPostID

        -- Set next loop
        Update @Posts Set GotTags = 1 Where PostID = @CurrentPostID
        Set @CurrentPostID = (Select Top 1 PostID From @Posts Where GotTags = 0)
    End

-- Return 2 recordsets, which are related by the PostID column found in both sets
Select * from @Posts
Select * From @PostTags
```

I prefer this type of solution over concatenating strings into one string and then splitting them later; it makes it easier to work with the data this way, allows to be more object oriented in C#, and lets you keep track of Tag ID's easier in case tags need to be removed or added to/from a post, you don't need to find a tag or match by name since you already have the ID.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously many websites do this, I want to know the best way..

The best way: there isn't one.

> and how it should be done in the real world?

Entity Framework would build out the query as you suggested and materialize the objects you need.  Yes there is duplicate data, but more often then not, the duplicate data is better with related data then trying to relate the information back together again.  The advantage is more readable code, and easier to query in a c# like language, with related records and change tracking (by default).

[Dapper can do the same thing - A parent object with it's children objects](https://www.tritac.com/bp-24-dapper-net-by-example).  It's [faster](http://mono.servicestack.net/benchmarks/), but it doesn't have change tracking, and the statements aren't c# like, they are (as far as I've seen) direct SQL, which makes writing dynamic queries a much harder.

> But surely there has to be a better way?

I don't know what *better* is.  Is it more efficent, less memory overhead, less network packets/size, more maintainable, more readable?

> Is there a way of doing this without replicating the post information for each tag row that is returned?

Yes, you could write a stored procedure to return multiple recordsets, materialize your objects, and *wire* them up manually.

[**This sounds like you are trying to optimize something you don't have a problem with.**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: Well no I don't have a problem with it right now, this is just a technical exercise - I just wanted to know if there was a simple solution or best practice to follow in this area but it seems not so whatever works best! Thanks for the useful information; I guess duplicate data isn't an issue at low volume and caching of Tags would be a decent approach were it a larger system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a query to return multiple recordsets. I wouldn't worry about over-optimizing until you do some performance testing.

I'm not sure about Dapper's recent support for one-to-many or many-to-many queries, but you might want to check out the new features in Insight.Database 4.0. There's a pre-release in nuget now.

Check out the pre-release docs. I'd love some feedback.

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/wiki/Proposed-4.0-Changes